# Install Canon printer LSB 2900B

Tags: command-line, printing, canon, 22.10, helpfile

0

I have been trying to install Canon Printer LBP2900B. I downloaded the driver, tried the generic driver, tried Synaptic package manager, downloaded all the updates from Canon, but none of these works.

Any ideas how to install and make it work on Ubuntu 22 LTS? Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 2):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?  Please elaborate on this and why it's relevant to the OP.  (This post has been posted **three times** identically to multiple posts and this causes flags for "duplicate posting" behavior)